# vscode lint extensions problems caused by different extensions

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, lint

I have a problem in `vscode` where I have a lot of extensions installed and a lot of problems are reported in the `Problems` view.

I've created a new django python project - but I want to set things up in such a way that the linters I am interested in will output correct problems.

So for `html` files I want to use [monosans.djlint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=monosans.djlint).

The idea being that all developers working on the project have the recommended extensions installed and any obtrusive ones disabled - but only for the project/workspace.

So given a basic html file, I see 14 problems reported - just to highlight the wider problem in my project.

**templates/test.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        {% for x in z %}
        <li>x</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const x = {{ data | safe }};

        const y = {
            foo: [{{ count_1 }}, {{ count_2 }}]
        };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Problems

The following screenshot is what I see in vsode:

[image: Problems and error highlighting]

Is it possible to actually identify what extension the problem is from?  I can see Microsoft Edge Tools - but not sure where the javascript problems are coming from.

### Files in Project

**NOTE:** I am using a folder - not a workspace for this.

**.vscode/settings.json**

```json
{
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance"
}
```

**/.djlintrc**

```json
{
  "profile": "django",
  "max_line_length": "120",
  "blank_line_after_tag": "load,extends,include"
}
```

### Python Packages

The following packages have been installed with `pip install`:

- djlint
- pycodestyle
- black

### Remedies

I've looked into recommendations in the `extensions.json` file, but not been prompted to do anything on loading of the project.

```json
{
    "unwantedRecommendations": [
        "ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools"
    ],
    "recommendations": [
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
        "monosans.djlint"
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to configure the project so that we can work to having zero Problems easily?
Should we be working in a [dev container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)?
Or do people live with the errors showing up in the Problems window?

Answer (score 0):

There is another setting in VS Code for Javascript inside script tags:

in settings.json, set

```
"html.validate.scripts": false
```